# Avoid loading datatable each time when i make an ajax call by clicking on each row

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF2 - I see my datatable reloading each time when i make an ajax call by clicking on each column row. Is there a way to stop loading each time i make an ajax call ? This creates problem by resetting my datatable to default values and i get a wrong value back at managed bean.

```
<h:inputText size="8" id="startDate"
value="#{contactBean.startDate}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText> - </h:outputText>
<h:inputText size="8" id="endDate" value="#{contactBean.endDate}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:inputText>
<h:commandButton value="Filter"  
actionListener="#{contactBean.loadAJAXFilterContentList}">
<f:ajax render=":form1:tableContents" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:dataTable id="tableContents"
value="#{contactBean.filterContentList}" var="crs"
binding="#{contactBean.dataTable}" border="1">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="contactTableHeader" value="Date/Time" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink action="#{contactBean.loadPreviewScreenContents(crs)}">
            <h:outputText title="#{crs.dateTime}" value="#{crs.dateTime}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" type="date" />
            </h:outputText>

            <f:ajax render=":form1:previewScreen" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>


<h:panelGrid id="previewScreen">
    <h:outputText styleClass="PreviewHeader"
        value="Preview of #{contactBean.previewCntDateTime}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

So in the above case whenever i click the column it calls the filterContentList() method in my managed bean instead of calling loadPreviewScreenContents(crs) directly.
My bean is RequestScoped. I tried with SessionScope,ViewScope but these 2 scopes retain my previous states like i have other ajax functions in my page and it retains that state. So i cant use Session or ViewScopes in this case.

Is there a solution ?

```
Bean code:
@ManagedBean(name = "contactBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ContactManagedBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
List<ContactResponseBean> filterContentList = new ArrayList<ContactResponseBean>();
ContactRequestBean contactRequestBean = new ContactRequestBean();
ContactResponseBean crs = new ContactResponseBean();
private String logText;
HtmlDataTable dataTable;
public void setFilterContentList(List<ContactResponseBean> filterContentList) {
this.filterContentList = filterContentList;
}
public void setFilterContentList(List<ContactResponseBean> filterContentList) {
    this.filterContentList = filterContentList;
}
public Date getPreviewCntDateTime() {
    return previewCntDateTime;
}
public void setPreviewCntDateTime(Date previewCntDateTime) {
    this.previewCntDateTime = previewCntDateTime;
}
public String getLogText() {
    return logText;
}

public void setLogText(String logText) {
    this.logText = logText;
}
public HtmlDataTable getDataTable() {
    return dataTable;
}

public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable) {
    this.dataTable = dataTable;
}
public ContactResponseBean getCrs() {
    return crs;
}
public void setCrs(ContactResponseBean crs) {
    this.crs = crs;
}

   public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public void loadAJAXFilterContentList() {
    filterButtonAjxFlag = true;
}

public List<ContactResponseBean> getFilterContentList() {   
        ContactRequestBean contactRequestBean = new ContactRequestBean();
        contactRequestBean.setUserId(getUserId());
        contactRequestBean.setSummaryType(getSummaryType());
        contactRequestBean.setStartDate(getStartDate());
        contactRequestBean.setEndDate(getEndDate());
            ContactRequestBeanService crbs = new ContactRequestBeanService();
        filterContentList = crbs.getFilterContentList(contactRequestBean);
    return filterContentList;
}
public void loadPreviewScreenContents(){
crs = (ContactResponseBean) dataTable.getRowData();
setPreviewCntDateTime(crs.getDateTime());
}
}
```

Comment: You must differ between getter methods and action methods in JSF. Putting some logic into your getter method is not a best practice, as this method should only return the value stored in a variable. Use a [`preRenderView` event](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/) to initialize your data only once, when your page is loaded, or just do it in a `@PostConstruct` method. Also you should provide the backing bean content in the question.

Comment: I dont think preRenderView is relevant to my question because i want the table to be called only when i make the ajax call but here its called even before my ajax method is called. i mean once i click the table row it loads the table and then it calls my ajax method which is wrong. I want it to just call my ajax method and not the table.

Comment: I mean, you can't control when the table list getter (table's `value`) is going to be called. In fact you can't control when any getter method is going to be called, that depends on the view. Appart from that I can't understand why are you pretending to use the `@RequestScope`, you are complaining about this scope is reloading your table, however you also say the other scopes maintain your previous states. What do you exactly want to achieve? I can't help you without your bean code.

Comment: attached is my bean code. When i use RequestScope - i dont want to load this table automatically because i want only my ajax method to be called. When i use Session/View scopes then it stores my previous states which means i have other ajax button calls in this code and so it maintains those datas before i click this table column ajax call - which is wrong as it loads old datas respective to other ajax calls respective to command button ajax call/dropdown ajax calls. Makes sense ?

Comment: BTW i got my problem solved now but i got another problem now while solving this. Iam unable to retrieve my other form field values into backing bean like i have fields like startdate,enddate fields which are not getting passed to the backing bean when i make this table column click. idk why. any idea ? All the code is inside one single form.

Comment: I think you can do it with `@ViewScoped` and all the logic you have in the getter of the content list being put into a `@PostConstruct` method. Your table will remain with the same values and your `previewScreen` object will be properly updated with the given value. Appart from that, the rest of the form fields should be set before processing the action method.

Comment: This doesnt help because PostConstruct can be given on a method with no return parameters - in my case my getList has a return list. Another thing is - This table list has to be loaded while initial form load too. Iam now figuring out how to bring the form fields back to backing bean while making ajax call on my command button which is not happening now after fixing this loading problem.

Comment: Just load your list in postconstruct and save it in a property. Then, return this property in the getter.

Comment: woww ... worked just like i expected !!! thanks very much Biker :-)

Comment: but now iam facing another problem while solving this - other form field values (start date - end date) are not getting assigned to backing bean when i make an ajax call... any idea ?

Comment: I got it working by adding the execute="@form" for the command button :-)